# share variable among pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple JavaScript file which takes care of the translation on the page. So if user wants to see a page in e.g. English, he clicks on it and the page translates itself. Everything works great except when user goes to another page.

Now my JavaScript is re-loaded again, and default language kicks in. Which is undesirable - I want my JavaScript to remember what language user has specified.

Here is my JavaScript code to show what I am doing

```
//translations
var language = "en";
$(function () {
    translatePage();

    $("#PageLanguages li").on("click", function (attr) {
        var selLang = $(this).data("language");
        if (selLang) {
            language = selLang;
        }

        translatePage();
    });

    function translatePage() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'languages.xml',
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find('translation').each(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var text = $(this).find(language).text();
                    $("#" + id).text(text);
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                var x = err;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

As you can see, I am storing language (the one user has specified) in my `language` variable at the top.

What do I need to do, when I would like to website to share a variable among all pages (such as in this case) ?

Comment: store language variable in cookies or localstorage

Comment: Or server-side in a database. There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can go about doing this. But I'll list just three. If you want the JavaScript approach (which relies on JavaScript being enabled/supported by the browser):

```
var language = localStorage.getItem("language") || "";

if(language !== "")
{
    // Set the language for content in here
}
else
{
    // Store the language in LocalStorage here.
    localStorage.setItem("language", "en-us");
}
```

Alternatively, you could store stuff like this in your Database (server-side), but I would advise against storing such things in your own database unless you absolutely need to ensure that value will exist when you need it.

Another option is appending something like `language=en-us` to your query string when they click on a hyperlink or button. And you could then use JavaScript or a server-side language on the next page to get this data from the query string.

Answer (score 3):

My advice here is browser based , using local storage with the modern browsers

```
localStorage.setItem('language', 'eng');

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');

console.log(retrievedLanguage); /// prints eng
```

Answer (score 2):

If target browsers are html5 compliant , try local storage :

```
//set data
localStorage.setItem("language", language);

// get data
var language = localStorage.getItem("language");
```

will be available for all pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is different way to keep the language variable in all pages.

> 1) Use the language string in **URL** itself ex :
>   https://www.paypal.com/**ar**/webapps/mpp/home
>
> 2) Call server to know the language.
>
> 3) Store in cookie as specified by uzaif
>
> 4) Using **localStorage**